# Parts missing in an XSLT transformation output

Tags: xslt, xalan

I'm using a C++ version of Xalan 1.10 under Windows and I'm trying to produce an Apache FOP file out of an xml document.

The files are rather large and complex, but the following samples illustrate the problem just fine:

**Input.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <root-xml-element>
    <MyElement name="Some text"/>
  </root-xml-element>
```

**Stylesheet.xsl**

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0"
           xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
           xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:root>
      <xsl:text>(ROOT MATCHED)</xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="root-xml-element"/>  
    </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="root-xml-element">
    <xsl:text>(ROOT ELEMENT MATCHED)</xsl:text>
    <xsl:call-template name="MyTemplate"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="MyTemplate">
    <xsl:text>(MY TEMPLATE MATCHED)</xsl:text>
      <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="Master" page-width="29.7cm" page-height="21cm">
        </fo:simple-page-master>
      </fo:layout-master-set>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

The transformation completes without any errors but produces the following *incomplete* output:

**Output file from Xalan**

```
(ROOT MATCHED)(ROOT ELEMENT MATCHED)(MY TEMPLATE MATCHED)
```

As you can see, there are no `<fo:...>` tags in the output file. The template obviously does get applied.

When I run a .NET xslt processor against those very same files, I get the output I expect:

**Output file from a .NET XSLT processor**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
   (ROOT MATCHED)(ROOT ELEMENT MATCHED)(MY TEMPLATE MATCHED)
    <fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:simple-page-master master-name="Master" page-width="29.7cm" page-height="21cm" />
    </fo:layout-master-set>
  </fo:root>
```

The same transformation also works when applied from Java Xalan version (don't know exactly which one). On the other hand the command-line Xalan executable produces the same incomplete output, so the chances are it's not my code that messes up something (or is it?).

What's going on here? Any ideas what to check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your output method is set to text. I suspect Xalan is only outputting the actual text, and not the XML nodes; I can't remember off hand which is the correct behavior, so I'm not sure if it's Xalan or .NET that's behaving incorrectly (possibly neither if the spec's flexible), however, it should work if you change your output method to XML.

Comment: Thanks, when I change the output directive to 'xml' I do get the sample working as expected. For some weird reason the actual files I'm working with still produce an incomplete output but I'll go ahead and assume that it must be something else that now makes problems. I hope that the difference in behavior is not a consequence of the fact that my sample stylesheet doesn't actually output any data from the input document.

Comment: Found it. My stylesheet includes others, and in those stylesheets I had output directives set to 'text', effectivelly overriding the main directive. Thanks for your help!